# TextView как в стандартном калькуляторе

Tags: android, xml, textview, калькулятор

Вопрос следующий. Как в Android сделать TextView отображения символов как в стандартном калькуляторе, а именно:

1) Смещение символов влево, чтобы всегда были видны новые введенные символы, а старые заходили за пределы их отображения

2) Уменьшение шрифта символов при переполнении их кол-ва в отображаемом пространстве, желательно без использования атрибутов разряда Autosize Text, доступных только в API >25.

P.S использую именно TextView.

Comment: Вот он? https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_calculator/blob/master/src/com/android/calculator2/CalculatorEditText.java

Answer (score 0):

Вырвано из aosp-mirror:

```
public class CalculatorEditText extends EditText {

private final static ActionMode.Callback NO_SELECTION_ACTION_MODE_CALLBACK =
        new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Prevents the selection action mode on double tap.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
};

private final float mMaximumTextSize;
private final float mMinimumTextSize;
private final float mStepTextSize;

// Temporary objects for use in layout methods.
private final Paint mTempPaint = new TextPaint();
private final Rect mTempRect = new Rect();

private int mWidthConstraint = -1;
private OnTextSizeChangeListener mOnTextSizeChangeListener;

public CalculatorEditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CalculatorEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CalculatorEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.CalculatorEditText, defStyle, 0);
    mMaximumTextSize = a.getDimension(
            R.styleable.CalculatorEditText_maxTextSize, getTextSize());
    mMinimumTextSize = a.getDimension(
            R.styleable.CalculatorEditText_minTextSize, getTextSize());
    mStepTextSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CalculatorEditText_stepTextSize,
            (mMaximumTextSize - mMinimumTextSize) / 3);

    a.recycle();

    setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(NO_SELECTION_ACTION_MODE_CALLBACK);
    if (isFocusable()) {
        setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mMaximumTextSize);
    setMinHeight(getLineHeight() + getCompoundPaddingBottom() + getCompoundPaddingTop());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Hack to prevent keyboard and insertion handle from showing.
        cancelLongPress();
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    mWidthConstraint =
            MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getVariableTextSize(getText().toString()));
}

@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    super.onSaveInstanceState();

    // EditText will freeze any text with a selection regardless of getFreezesText() ->
    // return null to prevent any state from being preserved at the instance level.
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);

    final int textLength = text.length();
    if (getSelectionStart() != textLength || getSelectionEnd() != textLength) {
        // Pin the selection to the end of the current text.
        setSelection(textLength);
    }
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getVariableTextSize(text.toString()));
}

@Override
public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
    final float oldTextSize = getTextSize();
    super.setTextSize(unit, size);

    if (mOnTextSizeChangeListener != null && getTextSize() != oldTextSize) {
        mOnTextSizeChangeListener.onTextSizeChanged(this, oldTextSize);
    }
}

public void setOnTextSizeChangeListener(OnTextSizeChangeListener listener) {
    mOnTextSizeChangeListener = listener;
}

public float getVariableTextSize(String text) {
    if (mWidthConstraint < 0 || mMaximumTextSize <= mMinimumTextSize) {
        // Not measured, bail early.
        return getTextSize();
    }

    // Capture current paint state.
    mTempPaint.set(getPaint());

    // Step through increasing text sizes until the text would no longer fit.
    float lastFitTextSize = mMinimumTextSize;
    while (lastFitTextSize < mMaximumTextSize) {
        final float nextSize = Math.min(lastFitTextSize + mStepTextSize, mMaximumTextSize);
        mTempPaint.setTextSize(nextSize);
        if (mTempPaint.measureText(text) > mWidthConstraint) {
            break;
        } else {
            lastFitTextSize = nextSize;
        }
    }

    return lastFitTextSize;
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingTop() {
    // Measure the top padding from the capital letter height of the text instead of the top,
    // but don't remove more than the available top padding otherwise clipping may occur.
    getPaint().getTextBounds("H", 0, 1, mTempRect);

    final FontMetricsInt fontMetrics = getPaint().getFontMetricsInt();
    final int paddingOffset = -(fontMetrics.ascent + mTempRect.height());
    return super.getCompoundPaddingTop() - Math.min(getPaddingTop(), paddingOffset);
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingBottom() {
    // Measure the bottom padding from the baseline of the text instead of the bottom, but don't
    // remove more than the available bottom padding otherwise clipping may occur.
    final FontMetricsInt fontMetrics = getPaint().getFontMetricsInt();
    return super.getCompoundPaddingBottom() - Math.min(getPaddingBottom(), fontMetrics.descent);
}

public interface OnTextSizeChangeListener {
    void onTextSizeChanged(TextView textView, float oldSize);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) используй аттрибут android:gravity="right" (не путать с layout_gravity!)

2) AutosizeTextView доступно в SupportLibrary пример [тут](http://androidkt.com/autosizing-textviews/)

Comment: Его и использую. Всё, что он делает, помещает курсор вправо, но при этом при переполнении смещение влево не делает. Связано ли это с тем, что TextView лежит в RelativeLayout?

Comment: попробуй `android:gravity="end" android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="start"`

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо. Только желательно, чтобы тремя точками не заменялось продолжение того, что невозможно уместить на экран

Comment: тогда можно поставить ellipsize="none"